# How to cache images in memcached in php?

Tags: php, image, memcached

im trying to cache images in memcached. tested this code:

```
ob_start(); 
$image = imagecreatefrompng(ROOT_DIR."/img/welcome.png");
imagepng($image); 
$memcache->set("my_image", ob_get_contents(), false, 3600); 
ob_end_clean();
```

but not works. any suggestions?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error message? Is the cache item saved? Is it empty or corrupted?

Comment: Can you store other values with `$memcache->set()`? If you write the result of `ob_get_contents()` to a file, does it work?

Comment: Memcached has a maximum value length of 1MB. How big is your image?